# Different scaling of bars and Y-axis in jqplot & barcharts

Tags: jquery, jqplot, bar-chart

While using jqplot I have to create bar chart with 2 series, and each of them consists of 3 different values (categories). The problem is that first value is about 50000 and 2 others are about (-3) - (3). So while drawing it on one chart there are only 2 bars visible.
I was thinking about using LogRenderer for y-axis, however it did not seem to be working at all. The best option would be setting different y-axis for each tickgroup(category), however after searching I did not find any way to do this. (what is important that there must be only 2 series - it is date comparison so it is impossible to change what is in the series)

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Or is there any other way you would present all the data on one chart (mainly using bar chart).

JS fiddle with my working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/F5N4r/

The header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/armata007/jqplot/downloads/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/armata007/jqplot/downloads/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/armata007/jqplot/downloads/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/armata007/jqplot/downloads/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/armata007/jqplot/downloads/jqplot.enhancedLegendRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/armata007/jqplot/downloads/jqplot.logAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>​
```

The code:

```
var s1 = [50000, 0.11, 2.3];
var s2 = [55000, -0.20, 1.4];

var ticks = ['category 1', 'category 2', 'category 3'];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('plot', [s1, s2], {
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
        label: 'January 2012'},
    {
        label: 'February 2012'}
    ],
    legend: {
        show: true,
        placement: "outside",
        location: "s",
        renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            numberRows: 1
        },
        marginTop: "34px"
    },
    axes: {

        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: ticks
        },


        yaxis: {
            //renderer: $.jqplot.LogAxisRenderer,
            pad: 1.05,
            tickOptions: {
                formatString: '%d'
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

Result:
http://www.roslaw.pl/pics/2012-11-29_18-56-55_835341x930andWndpnd.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing with this myself and hopefully this will save someone some time.

You need to define a separate series for each one passed into the function 
(s1 and s2 in your case). The order you define them corresponds to the order they are passed.

```
series: [
    {
        label: 'January 2012',
    }, 
    {
        yaxis:'y2axis',
        label: 'February 2012'
    }
],

...

axes: {
    xaxis: {
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: "y axis 1"
        },
        y2axis: {
            label: 'y axis 2',
        }
}
```